# Understanding loading of font in PDFBox 2.0

Tags: pdfbox

I have finally succeeded in making PDFBox print my unicodes. 
But now, I would like to understand the solution that I have come up with.
The code below works and prints a `≥` to the page.

Two things do not work:

- changing 
  `PDType0Font.load(documentMock, systemResourceAsStream, true);`
  to
  `PDType0Font.load(documentMock, systemResourceAsStream, false);`
- changing 
  `final PDFont robotoLight = loadFontAlternative("Roboto-Light.ttf");` 
  to 
  `final PDFont robotoLight = loadFont("Roboto-Light.ttf");`

The first change prints two dots instead of the character.
**What does embedSubset do, since it does not work when set to false?**
The documentation is too sparse for me to understand.

The second change gives the following exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+2265 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding`
This problem has been covered in many other questions that pre-dates PDFBox 2.0 where there was a bug in handling unicodes.
So, they do not answer the question directly.
That aside, the problem is clear: I should not set the encoding to WinAnsiEncoding but something different. 
**But what should the encoding be?** and **why is there no UTF-8 encoding or similar available?**
There is no documentation in COSName about the many options.

```
public class SimpleReportUnicode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDDocument report = createReport();
        final String fileLocation = "c:/SimpleFormUnicode.pdf";
        report.save(fileLocation);
        report.close();
    }

    private static PDDocument createReport() throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        final PDFont robotoLight = loadFontAlternative("Roboto-Light.ttf");
        writeText(contentStream, robotoLight, 100, 650);

        contentStream.close();
        return document;
    }

    private static void writeText(PDPageContentStream contentStream, PDFont font, double x, double y) {
        try {
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount((float) x, (float) y);
            String unicode = "≥";
            contentStream.showText(unicode);
            contentStream.endText();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    private static PDFont loadFont(String location) {
        PDFont font;
        try {
            PDDocument documentMock = new PDDocument();
            InputStream systemResourceAsStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(location);
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.getInstance(COSName.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);
            font = PDTrueTypeFont.load(documentMock, systemResourceAsStream, encoding);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IO exception");
        }
        return font;
    }

    private static PDFont loadFontAlternative(String location) {
        PDDocument documentMock = new PDDocument();
        InputStream systemResourceAsStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(location);
        PDFont font;
        try {
            font = PDType0Font.load(documentMock, systemResourceAsStream, true);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IO exception");
        }
        return font;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
If you want to use the same font as in the code, Roboto is available here:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto
Add Roboto-Light.ttf to your classpath and the code should work out of the box.

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: The "U+2265 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding" is explained in the FAQ: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#fontencoding .  `PDType0Font.load()` works for me regardless if the last parameter is true or false. True means subset, false means entire font is used (i.e. file gets bigger: 100KB instead of 4KB).

Comment: _why is there no UTF-8 encoding or similar available?_ because the PDF specification doesn't have it.

Comment: Re _embedSubset_, we're always willing to improve the documentation. What is unclear, the word "embed" or the word "subset"? Or both?

Comment: _What PDFBox version are you using?_ 2.0.0 to be exact.

Comment: Wrt. the encoding, to sum it up, that means that WinAnsiEncoding is the right encoding, but I have to load the character separately if it is not supported.

Comment: _What is unclear, the word "embed" or the word "subset"? Or both?_ Both in context. 
I do not understand why an embedded subset works while the whole embedded set does not work. 
I do not understand why it works for you while it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I solved the problem with characters not rendering correctly when setting the embedSubset to false. 
I updated PDFBox from 2.0.0 to 2.0.7 and now the problem is not there anymore.
Tilman, will you sum up your comments to an answers so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

- The problem with embedSubsets went away by using version 2.0.7. (Btw 2.0.8 was released today);
- The problem "U+2265 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding" is explained in the [FAQ](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#fontencoding) and the solution is to use `PDType0Font.load()` which you already did in your working version;
- There is no UTF-8 encoding for fonts because it isn't available in the PDF specification;
- using embedSubsets true produces a 4KB file, with false the file is 100KB because the full font is embedded, so false is usually best.